# Convert time format 2019-01-21 05:05:11.000000 to 1548060780546

Tags: javascript, date, timestamp

In my angular application I'm getting logged time as 2019-01-21 05:05:11.000000  (timezone = UTC and timezone_type = 3) from back-end API. In the same way I'm getting current time using following code.

```
const now = new Date();
const currentTime = now.getTime();
```

I got output "1548152940836" for currentTime.

I used getTimezoneOffset() method to return the time difference between UTC time and local time.

```
  const loggedTime = new Date(lastLoginAt).getTime();
  const now = new Date();
  const currentTime = now.getTime();

 if ((currentTime - (loggedTime - (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000)) > (7200 * 1000)){ }
```

In my application, I want to get the time difference between logged time and currentTime and check whether that time difference is larger than 7200 seconds. 
But this gives me large number from time difference which is always greater than 7200,000 milliseconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `lastLoginAt` string is exactly formatted like `2019-01-21 05:05:11.000000` and that represents a UTC timestamp, then you first need to change it to `2019-01-21T05:05:11.000000Z` before parsing.  This is the ISO 8601 extended UTC form (also RFC 3339), which is required by the ECMAScript spec.

Then you can simply subtract the timestamps.  No need to adjust for time zone offset, because both values are UTC based.

(For convenience, you can also use `Date.parse` and `Date.now` rather than allocating `Date` object instances.  Both return numeric timestamps.)

```
const loggedTime = Date.parse(lastLoginAt.replace(' ', 'T') + 'Z');
const currentTime = Date.now();

if (currentTime - loggedTime > 7200000) {

}
```

Alternatively, consider using a library such as [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/) or [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/), which provide functions to make this even easier.